# Is it possible to draw more than one object using OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: java, android, object, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

This is an update to a question I recently asked, but with new problems after I tried some stuff. What I want is to draw multiple circles on the screen. I created a class for the circle object. In my renderer class, I created an array list of these circles each with a different position. When called to draw, it only draws one of them. I logged what was going on and each object is being called to get drawn, but it seems only one appears on the screen. It's not just my circles. It appears throughout personal testing OpenGL ES 2.0 will only draw one object on the screen. I have no idea how to fix this. Is there something special I have to do in OpenGL ES 2.0? Here is my code. Ignore the incredibly sloppy and inefficient code right now. I am aware of it and will fix it later. Here is my circle object class:

GLCircle:

```
package com.background.gl.objects;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glDrawArrays;
import static android.opengl.Matrix.multiplyMM;
import static android.opengl.Matrix.setIdentityM;
import static android.opengl.Matrix.translateM;
import static com.background.gl.glcirclebackgroundanimation.Constants.BYTES_PER_FLOAT;

import java.util.Random;

import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.util.Log;

import com.background.gl.data.VertexArray;
import com.background.gl.helper.TextureShaderProgram;

public class GLCircle {
    private static final int POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT = 2;
    private static final int TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT = 2;
    private static final int STRIDE = (POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT
    + TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT) * BYTES_PER_FLOAT;

    public  float x;
    public  float y;
    protected  float[] wallBounds;
    protected  boolean positiveX, positiveY;
    public  boolean nullify;
    protected  float xCounter = 0f;
    protected  float yCounter = 0f;
    public  float[] bounds;
    protected Random ran;

    private float[] VERTEX_DATA = {
        // Order of coordinates: X, Y, S, T
        // Triangle Fan
        0f, 0f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
        -0.25f, -0.25f, 0f, 0.9f,
        0.25f, -0.25f, 1f, 0.9f,
        0.25f, 0.25f, 1f, 0.1f,
        -0.25f, 0.25f, 0f, 0.1f,
        -0.25f, -0.25f, 0f, 0.9f };

    private final VertexArray vertexArray;

    public GLCircle(float x, float y) {
        vertexArray = new VertexArray(VERTEX_DATA);
        ran = new Random();
        wallBounds = new float[4];
        nullify = false;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void bindData(TextureShaderProgram textureProgram) {
        //Bind the position data to the shader attribute
        vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(
            0,
            textureProgram.getPositionAttributeLocation(),
            POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT,
            STRIDE);
        //Bind the texture coordinate data to the shader attribute
        vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(
                POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT,
                textureProgram.getTextureCoordinatesAttributeLocation(),
                TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT,
                STRIDE);
        }

    public void drawCircle() {
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);
    }


    public float getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return this.y;
    }



    public  boolean isPositiveX() {
        return positiveX;
    }



    public  boolean isPositiveY() {
        return positiveY;
    }


    public float[] getBounds(float ranX, float ranY) {
        if(!positiveX) {
            /*if(ranX >= 0f) {
                wallBounds[0] = 1.05f + ranX;
            } else {*/
                this.wallBounds[0] = 1.05f + ranX;
            //}
        } else {
            /*
            if(ranX >= 0f) {
                wallBounds[0] = 1.05f - ranX;
            } else {*/
                this.wallBounds[1] = 1.05f - ranX;
            //}
        }
        if(!positiveY) {
            this.wallBounds[2] = 1.75f + ranY;
        } else {
            this.wallBounds[3] = 1.75f - ranY;
        }

        return this.wallBounds;
    }

    public void setPos(float[] modelMatrix, 
            float[] projectionMatrix, TextureShaderProgram textureProgram,
            int texture, float x, float y, String log) {
        setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
        translateM(modelMatrix, 0, 0f, 0.01f, 0f);
        final float[] temp = new float[16];
        multiplyMM(temp, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, temp.length);

        textureProgram.useProgram();
        textureProgram.setUniforms(projectionMatrix, texture);
        bindData(textureProgram);
        drawCircle();
        Log.d("Drawing", "Drawing " + log);
    }

    public void scaleCircle(float[] modelMatrix, float x, float y, float z) {
        Matrix.scaleM(modelMatrix, 0, x, y, z);
    }

    public void storeResults(float[] results) {
        this.x = results[0];
        this.y = results[1];
    }

    public void translateCircle(float x, float[] modelMatrix, float[] projectionMatrix) {
        setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
        translateM(modelMatrix, 0, /*-0.001f*/ x, -3f, -2f);
        final float[] temp = new float[16];
        multiplyMM(temp, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, temp.length);
    }
}
```

Again, I'm aware of most things I'm doing incorrectly, but currently I just need to figure out why I can't draw multiple objects on the screen. Here is my renderer code:

```
package com.background.gl.glcirclebackgroundanimation;

import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glClear;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glClearColor;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glViewport;
import static android.opengl.Matrix.multiplyMM;
import static android.opengl.Matrix.setIdentityM;
import static android.opengl.Matrix.translateM;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.util.Log;

import com.background.gl.helper.TextureShaderProgram;
import com.background.gl.objects.GLCircle;
import com.background.gl.objects.Mallet;
import com.background.gl.objects.Table;
import com.background.gl.util.MatrixHelper;
import com.background.gl.util.TextureHelper;

public class CircleDynamicBackgroundRenderer implements Renderer {
private final Context context;

    private final float[] projectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] modelMatrix = new float[16];
    protected static float ranX, 
    ranY, ranSignX, ranSignY, ranSignVeloX, ranSignVeloY;
    public boolean logNums;
    private Table table;
    private Mallet mallet;
    private List<GLCircle> circles;
    private GLCircle circle2;
    float xPos, yPos;
    int x = 1;
    float[] bounds;
    Random ran;
    private TextureShaderProgram textureProgram;

    private int texture;


    public CircleDynamicBackgroundRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        circles = new ArrayList<GLCircle>();
        xPos = 0.1f;
        ran = new Random();
        logNums = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        Log.w("Width and height", Integer.toString(width) + ", " + Integer.toString(height));
        MatrixHelper.perspectiveM(projectionMatrix, 90, (float) width
                / (float) height, 1f, 10f);

        for(int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {
            circles.get(i).translateCircle(circles.get(i).x, modelMatrix, projectionMatrix);
        }
//      /circle2.translateCircle(circle2.x, modelMatrix);
        /*final float[] temp = new float[16];
        multiplyMM(temp, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, temp.length);*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        table = new Table();
        mallet = new Mallet();

        textureProgram = new TextureShaderProgram(context);

        texture = TextureHelper.loadTexture(context, R.drawable.air_hockey_surface);
        //texture2 = TextureHelper.loadTexture(context, R.drawable.air_hockey_surface_2);
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            GLCircle circle = new GLCircle(generateRanFloats()[0], generateRanFloats()[1]);
            circles.add(circle);
            /*circle[i].x = circle[i].getX();
            circle[i].y = circle[i].getY();
            circle[i].bounds = circle[i].getBounds();*/
        }
            //circle2 = new GLCircle(generateRanFloats()[0], generateRanFloats()[1]);
        Log.d("Circles size", Integer.toString(circles.size()));
        Log.d("circles", Float.toString(circles.get(1).getX()) + " " + Float.toString(circles.get(2).getX()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
        //Clear the rendering surface
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        for(int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {
        circles.get(i).setPos(modelMatrix, projectionMatrix, textureProgram, texture, circles.get(i).x, circles.get(i).y, "1");         if(logNums) {
            Log.d("Circle1, c2", Float.toString(circles.get(i).x) + ", " + Float.toString(circles.get(i).x));
            logNums = false;
        }
        //Log.d("Circles", Float.toString(circles.get(i).x));
        }
    }

    public float[] generateRanFloats() {
        ranSignX = ran.nextFloat();
        ranSignY = ran.nextFloat();
        ranSignX = ranSignX > 0.5f? -1:1;
        ranSignY = ranSignY > 0.5f? -1:1;
        ranSignVeloX = ran.nextFloat();
        ranSignVeloY = ran.nextFloat();
        ranX = ran.nextFloat() * 1.05f;
        ranY = ran.nextFloat() * 1.75f;  
        ranX = ranSignX > 0.5? -ranX:ranX;
        ranY = ranSignY > 0.5? -ranY:ranY;
        Log.d("Generated", Float.toString(ranX));
        return new float[] {ranX, ranY};
    }

}
```

It's been two days now and I cannot for the live of me figure out what is wrong and how to fix this. I really need to figure out a way to fix this. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. If you need to see more code, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Per the last discussion - did you work on the perspective matrix ? I would recommend first starting with the ortho projection, get your code working, then move to working with perspective projection. You can use the below as a starting point for ortho projection.

mat4.ortho(-1.0, 1.0, -1, 1.0, -10.0, 100.0, projectionMatrix);

Also remove all the z translations in your code, make your code work on xy, then add z translations.

PS: Isnt it better to continue in the same thread as ([OpenGL ES 2.0 only draws the object once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978084/opengl-es-2-0-only-draws-the-object-once/21978795#21978795)) ?

Comment: I wasn't sure what to do. I can delete this a go back to that one. I actually don't even need to use the perspective projection. I have no idea why I started it with it. I'm staying in 2d, so I should've went with ortho from the start. I may just rewrite it again with an orthographical projection, and then see if the problem still arises. Can I still translate using an orthographical projection? I only know how to translate using a projection matrix.

Comment: Try replacing the `MatrixHelper.perspectiveM` call with MatrixHelper.orthoM(projectionMatrix, 0, -1.0, 1.0, -1, 1.0, -10.0, 100.0)